# Elastic search queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a large database in elastic search. I want to get data from that for some analysis. The size of the data that I want to get from the database is 25,000. That means there are nearly 25,000 results for my search query. Now I want get this all data into a csv file. For that firstly I installed csv plugin to my server. But when I set the size as 25,000 it doesn't display all data.

How can I get this all data set into a csv file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the specific plugin you're using and some idea of where it cuts off in the data. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Logstash](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) with an [elasticsearch input](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) and a [csv output](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-csv.html)! The following is a simple configuration that you can use to export ES data into a CSV file:

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        port => 9200
        index => "your_index"
        query => '{ "query": { "match_all": { } } }'
    }
}
output {
    csv {
        path => "/path/to/you/csv/file.csv"
        fields => ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
    }
}
```

Save that configuration in the `logstash.conf` file and then simply run it with `bin/logstash -f logstash.conf`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use Logstash?

Comment: Easiest is to read their Getting started guide at http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html

Comment: I type the code to download and extract the logstash binary and run it with a very simple configuration in the command prompt. But it says that 'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Why is that?

Comment: You can also click on this https://download.elastic.co/logstash/logstash/logstash-1.4.2.zip and download the ZIP from your browser. Then you can extract it and get going.